# Consistent font size in EPS image that are scaled?

Tags: diagrams, fontsize, scaling, eps

Assume that at creation time (of an EPS image) the final 'size' of the image is not known. However, this one EPS is used multiple times in different sizes within different documents.
But the font size of text (e.g., axes labels) should be consistent.

Example: In one `.tex` use

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{my_plotted_function.eps}
```

and in another use

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{my_plotted_function.eps}
```

but ensure, that the axes labels are shown with `12pt` in both figures.

Is there another way/vector graphics format to reach this functionality? (`pstricks`, `tikz` is not a solution, since it's not a supported export format.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177091/parametrization-of-font-size-in-eps-image?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

[`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) allows for this by default since it inserts the `<replacement>` of `<tag>` at compile-time:

```
\psfrag{<tag>}{<replacement>}
```

So you have to create the document with appropriate tags that can be replaced within your document. Here is a minimal example, taken from the [`auto-pst-pdf` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf)  on CTAN. The example image is [`example.eps`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/auto-pst-pdf/example.eps):

[image: psfrag maintains consistent font size when image is scaled]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{psfrag}% http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag
\begin{document}

% psfrag setup
\psfrag{[Mp]}{$M_p$}%
\psfrag{[hb]}{$\mathbf h$}%
\psfrag{[epb]}{$\mathbf{e}_p(n)$}%
\psfrag{[evh]}{$\hat{e}_v(n)$}%
\psfrag{[epsv]}{$\varepsilon_v(n)$}%
\psfrag{[ev]}{$e_v(n)$}% 

Original image: \par
\includegraphics{example} \par\bigskip\bigskip%

Scaled 50\%: \par
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example} \par\bigskip\bigskip

Scaled 150\%: \par
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{example}
\end{document}​
```

It is obvious that the `<replacement>` text maintains a consistent font size, based on the document default. You may have to adjust the placement of the `<replacement>` based on the image size.

Answer (score 1):

`psfrag` might be your friend if the text in the eps is not too obscured by whatever wrote the EPS, it should allow you to replace the text in the EPS file by LaTeX-typeset text over the top, which of course can be any size you wish.