# Correct uniform font formatting for included graphics

Tags: fonts, graphics, formatting, pdf, eps

## Uniform Font Formatting for Included Graphics as in the Rest of the Text

This question is not about vector or raster imagery, but about the application of ***uniform font*** in the entire file including axis labels of graphics! Has anyone experience with types of graphics files which do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{PlotGraphics1.eps}
\includegraphics{PlotGraphics2.pdf}
\includegraphics{PlotGraphics3.jpeg}
\includegraphics{PlotGraphics4.png}
\end{document}
```

I search for one which to which LaTeX can apply correct font formatting (e.g. for legends, axis, ...) at including it in the LaTeX document? Then I do not have to convert my MATLAB plots etc. to tikz at first.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please edit your question: As it is it's hard to understand what you want exactly. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: As Martin wrote, please try te be more specific regarding what you want/need. Also, if you're only concern with `matlab2tikz` is speed, I would be very surprised it is really that a showstopper unless you are creating a document with 1000+ figures that needs recompilation every 10 seconds...

Comment: @Xavier: To what in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436 are you refering to?

Comment: Nothing specific, just welcoming you to TeX.sx. I would only encourage you to make your question more specific, as this is truly a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. The broader / less specific your question, the harder it is for others to answer and help you.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I hope the question has become clear!?

Comment: Specifically for Postscript images (not rasterized or PDF), you can use [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) to provide uniform fonts with the document and image.

Comment: @Werner: Could you formulate a general answer about graphics types out of this? This package seems to be the one I was looking for for a long time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically for (encapsulated) Postscript images you can use [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) to substitute "tags" within the image with your own LaTeX constructions (equations, picture environments, etc.). The advantage with such an approach is that you can even scale the included graphics and `psfrag` will still be able to keep a consistent font size. As an example, see [Consistent font size in EPS image that are scaled?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43712/5764) The requirement in such a use case would be to specify a LaTeX equivalent construction for each tag in your image (for each image).

There exists no equivalent "`pdffrag`", unfortunately, since PDFs could be considered a pre-compiled (and therefore also usually smaller/faster) version of Postscript. See [Why is there no `pdffrag` package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475/5764)

Rasterized image formats like PNG and JPG are stripped of any knowledge of text elements - all components are considered graphics, in a pixelated and non-scalable form.

Comment: For oblivious people like me, the usage of the `psfrag` package only makes sense if you use the `latex` compiler and not `pdflatex`. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Compiling_with_latex for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are asking for a graph package, which uses LaTeX' fonts for labels, If so, check out [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net). It has a nice package for graphs (and you can create almost any figure with it). Can write PDF directly, and that works very well with pdflatex.

Comment: That is okay that there are nice packages for producing graphs. But I want to know which graphics file type support reading in text such that LaTeX formats this text for me to the correct shape.

Comment: @strpeter: None. LaTeX does not modify the graphics before including them. So it is up to you to generate the graphics with the right fonts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the font **shape** is concerned an option would be to provide access to the `type1` and/or `otf` fonts to your graphing program.

On Windows, I did this for more than 10 years, by installing the fonts in the regular `Fonts` directory.

I used this  mostly for the [Mayura Draw](http://www.mayura.com/) drawing program, in order to customize `gnuplot` plots, requiring to slightly edit its config files, and to provide `ghostview` and/or `eps2pdf` with the path to `type1` fonts files.

This works for `Inkscape` two, and I guess for `Matlab`, by using the `otf` version of the `latin modern` fonts (that I use for text).

But this does not solve the **size** problem: a `psfrag` is provided in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43712/consistent-font-size-in-eps-image-that-are-scaled).

As I definitely use pdflatex, I switched  to `tikz` for a few months.